# React-native youtube-iframe is not showing video

Tags: reactjs, react-native, youtube

Hi everyone I'm just triyng to show Youtube videos I copied this code from doc of this package but nothing happens in android emulator.

code

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useRef } from "react";
import { Button, View, Alert } from "react-native";
import YoutubePlayer from "react-native-youtube-iframe";

export default function App() {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  const onStateChange = useCallback((state) => {
    if (state === "ended") {
      setPlaying(false);
      Alert.alert("video has finished playing!");
    }
  }, []);

  const togglePlaying = useCallback(() => {
    setPlaying((prev) => !prev);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <YoutubePlayer
        height={300}
        width={300}
        play={playing}
        videoId={"iee2TATGMyI"}
        onChangeState={onStateChange}
      />
      <Button title={playing ? "pause" : "play"} onPress={togglePlaying} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

result

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnGxZ.png)

packageJson

```
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.0",
"react-native-webview": "^11.3.2",
"react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.0.1"
```

Another component my trying    with class component.
This also gives white screen and no playing video.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useRef ,Component} from "react";
import { Button, View, Alert } from "react-native";
import YoutubePlayer from "react-native-youtube-iframe";

export default class YtComp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
    };
  }
  stateChange(){
    
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'}}>
       <YoutubePlayer
        height={300}
        width={300}
        play={true}
        videoId={"whPcAVEwdKY&ab"}
        onChangeState={this.stateChange()}

      />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: can you mention the skd version of the emulator that you are using. I am also looking for the solution to this issue. But it is appearing in lower Android sdk versions like 22, 24, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the width. I had a somehow similar issue with the layout that prevented the player from showing. The component is there, it's just not showing on the screen. So I suggest you focus on the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I tested locally and it worked. Perhaps you could change the function name onStateChange to something different, that could actually solve it. Another option try deleting your node_modules and reinstalling them.

Comment: Can u share code. Also I put my another try

Comment: Anyone to help me with this